Has anyone axiomatized and studied a geometry with parallel points?
People have studied both geometries with parallel lines and geometries without parallel lines. However, in those geometries, any two distinct points can be joined by a line, i.e, there are no "parallel" points. I am now wondering if anyone has axiomatized and studied geometries with both parallel points and parallel lines, and also geometries with parallel points but no parallel lines. I would love to read such texts.

Consider the subset ${(x,y,0)|x,y\in{\mathbf R}} \cup {(x,y,1)|x,y\in{\mathbf R}}$ of ${\mathbf R}^3$.

Of course, some of these are quite interesting and important. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_geometry
